# text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, overflow, css

In [this](http://luigisettembrini.gov.it/listituto/presentazione/) page there are some links at the left sidebar that get cropped with:

```
.widget-area .textwidget li {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

In Firefox/Chrome it's displayed properly:
[image: Screenshot from Firefox/Chrome]

Unfortunately Internet Explorer 8/9/10...:
[image: Screenshot from IE 10]

The problem isn't IE 10 support for text-overflow:ellipsis.. for example [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x4Pxk/1/) works on IE 10 too! What's wrong with my implementation? I also tried to add -ms-text-overflow:ellipsis, without any luck.

Comment: add display property to block..width as 100%..or the one you wish to hav..or set max width..

Comment: Another example of this implementation working on IE 10: http://multiformeingegno.it/

Comment: Ok i dont hav access to ie css now..i ll update my code later..

Comment: it's odd, because IE was the browser that first implemented `ellipsis`, way back in IE5.5, so you'd think they'd get it right.

Comment: meanwhile can u post ur code

Comment: It's a PHP website.. check out the HTML source code at the link provided in the first post.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Removing the `word-wrap: break-word` property should help.

Comment: As that wasn't in the CSS above or in my css, this was mildly confusing.  Adding "word-wrap: normal" does seem to fix it though.

Comment: This makes no sense to me, but it is the correct answer.  Thank you duri.

Comment: Note: IE11 (and probably below) will not work with this if there are `<br>` in front of the text!

Answer (score 2):

add width property to your CSS code..this would help..

Comment: To what? li? .widget-area .textwidget ul? textwidget div..?

Comment: within li place div.. i mean let each li element have div which then contains your content.. and apply width or max width to your inner div (newly added)

Comment: Tried now but didn't work. The width gets reduced (I tried with width:190px) but the links are still on 2 lines.

Comment: give display: inline-block property to your inner div (div inside li)

Answer (score 1):

For IE you should add some extra code..like changing ur width property..or try using a dotdotdot jquery plugin..that would be an alternate solution..
Like this

http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl

Edit:
Follow this link

[Quirksmode textoverflow](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html)

which tells you to set the  **width:100%**  for IE..

Comment: A nice solution is using jQuery for this little thing? Naah. It should be an easy fix, like moving the 3 CSS declarations to the container.. something like that! I Googled but I can't seem to find anything interesting.

Comment: Nice solution since its cross browser implementation..and for good presentation..the simplest solution is not always the best one..

Comment: try run this in ie jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/kaJ3L/1/