# text-overflow: ellipsis not working in <td> IE9

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have tried the following code to my td, but no good sign.

```
.td_class{
max-width:100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow : ellipsis;
-ms-text-overflow : ellipsis; 
}
```

any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work on IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664195/text-overflowellipsis-doesnt-work-on-ie)

Comment: use `white-space: nowrap` without it ellipsis is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
td
{
    max-width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work, if you wrap the text in the `<th>` in an additional element and apply the `width` and `overflow` to that:

http://jsfiddle.net/nkLav9f7/6/

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><span>This is a really long header</span></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

table, td { border: solid 1px black }

th
{
    max-width: 50px;
}

span
{
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set "**word-wrap: bread-word**" in other style like "*{word-wrap: bread-word}", please change it to "**word:wrap: normal**". It works for me.