# Truncate(with 3 dots "...") content in IE and chrome doesnt work

Tags: html, css

I have the following situation:

HTML:

```
 <input class="BWForm_form-control BWTextBox" disabled="disabled" id="something" title="Test Firma" type="text" value="Test Firma 11111111111111111111111111111"></input>
```

CSS:

```
    // trunicate text with "..." 3 dots, if the content is larger than the current width
input[disabled="disabled"]{
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

In IE and chrome it doesnt work, except in FireFox.

I tried also:
[text-overflow:ellipsis doesn't work on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664195/text-overflowellipsis-doesnt-work-on-ie),
[text-overflow: ellipsis not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993067/text-overflow-ellipsis-not-working)

But it didn't take affect..

It would be nice without having a fixed width, because the width of these input fields are different.

Ty for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
input[disabled="disabled"] {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px; /* Set a size */
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If you  have to set ellipsis you must set a width...the size matters in ellipsis :)

Comment: Strange, it should work on IE...what version you use? You can check here the use of ellipsis on IE - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I checked it against IE 7,IE 8,IE 9 and IE 10 and none of them is working with it ...

Comment: Try this fix: input[disabled="disabled"]:before {
  content: ''; /* IE ellipsis fix */
}

Comment: I inserted this input[disabled="disabled"]:before { content: ''; /* IE ellipsis fix */ }  infront of my existing "input[disabled="disabled"]", but I can't see any changes ...

Comment: Hmmm...IE is so tricky...try implement this rule too in the style - word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: hmm.. right now the relevant code looks like this: "input[disabled="disabled"]:before { content: ''; word-wrap: break-word;/* IE ellipsis fix */
                              
} 

//problems in IE 
input[disabled="disabled"] {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100px; /* Set a size */
    ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    /**/margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
" it does not matter wether I remove this  "word-wrap: break-word;" ...

Comment: the vendor prefix usually begins with `-` so how about `-ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;` instead of `ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;`?

Comment: @ArtjomB. You are right...my fault...sorry and thanks... i will edit my solution